# Pip install requirements.txt in venv: How to ignore system site packages of different version?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-venv, requirements.txt

I am in a virtual environment which shares the system site packages (created with `venv` in Python 3.5), and I would like to install all packages in a given requirements.txt into this venv. The system-wide python installation is read-only, so I cannot modify it.

Now, for example, my requirements.txt lists, among many others,

```
SomePackage==2.0
```

as requirement, while the system installation already contains `SomePackage-1.0`. Pip thus tries to uninstall `SomePackage-1.0` to upgrade to version 2.0. This, however, fails because the system-wide python installation is read-only.

Is there a way to run `pip install -r requirements.txt` in a way that ignores installed packages if they have a different version from the required one and just installs the required version into the venv?

I guess this would be similar to installing each package one by one and using `--ignore-installed` whenever the package is already present in a different version than the required one. This, however, seems quite cumbersome. Is there a better way?

Note that I am using a venv with shared system site packages because I want to avoid the installation of several huge packages each time I create a new venv. Thus I do not want to switch to a fully isolated venv, which would, of course, not have the above issue.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you have any idea why using `pip install -r requirements.txt --ignore-installed` doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

To list only the packages you need for your project inside venv, and not all global packages from your computer, **first** you have to activate the virtualenv, and **from (env)** to run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` command.

So you will have strictly listed the packages you need for the specified project.